# Copy to other worksheets depending on criteria

Tags: vba, excel, criteria, copy-paste

I am all new to VBA and are stuck. I have seen some Youtube videos and some threads here, but it is complicated for me - I hope, that some of you can help me :)

I use the macro below and have these obstacles with it.

1. When I run it, it leaves the first rows empty and when I insert new data and run it, Again, it just moves everything Down perfectly as I wanted it, but it dosent fill the empty cells - It just starts at row 17, because in the worksheet `Opgørsel` I have 17 rows filled with data - I dont know, why it jumps like that.
2. In sheet `opgørsel`, I have 12 options in cell `D3`  and depending on which option is chosen, I want it to copy it to that sheet - I have made 12 sheets as well - But I dont know how to make it like that.

.

```
Sub Copypastemeddata()
    Worksheets("Opgørsel").Activate
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
    Worksheets("Opsamling").Activate
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDownenter
End Sub
```

Comment: Please clarify what you want to see happen and what is actually happening.

Comment: 1. When i run the macro, i want it copy the inserted data into that sheet depending on, what is choosen in cell "D3" - I have 12 options and 12 sheets, that it needs to copy to.

2. Right now, when i say run macro, it just copies to the sheet "Opsamling" with 17 empty rows - I have 17 rows filled with data - I dont want it to jump 17 rows, i wanted to start from the top and just move Down, when i run the macro Again - also when there comes new data.

I hope that is more clarifying.

Comment: You may need to show more code as I can't see Opsamling or D3 referenced.

Comment: That is all the code that i have, i have made everything else manuelle - But i couldnt move further, because i needed help from vba.

Comment: My D3 options are:
"1. a";"2.b";3.c" and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what something might look like that uses D3 to target copying to another sheet. I expect this would have to be further refined as you supply more detail. This assume D3 hold a valid sheet name to copy to. It continually takes everything from the source sheet so you will end up with duplicate data. If you only want new rows transferred then you will need to track row count somewhere (potentially in another sheet).

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copypastemeddata()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sourceCell As Range
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Opgørsel")

    Set sourceCell = ws.Range("D3")  'Cell with sheet names for copying to

    With ws

          Set targetSheet = wb.Worksheets(sourceCell.Text)

          Dim nextRow As Long
          nextRow = GetLastRow(targetSheet, 1)
          nextRow = IIf(nextRow = 1, 1, nextRow + 1)

         .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy targetSheet.Range("A" & nextRow)

    End With

End Sub


Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long

    With ws

      GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row

    End With

End Function
```

Example:

[image: Test run]

Comment: Thank you so much, it looks very complicated - I just tried to copy it all and let it take a run, but it wont? it says "run-time error 9 - Subsript out of range".

Comment: I don't expect this to solve your problems. I think more information is required. It does show you how to use a value in a cell to determine which sheet to copy paste to and how to find the next row.

Comment: Just tried it, and it Works perfectly - Thank you so much! I wouldnt have done it, if i was working with in 5 months of time!
where should i Places these two "Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths" ?

Comment: You can simply do  targetSheet.Columns.AutoFit

Comment: You are simply my hero - Thank you so much!
- I have two last quetions.
1. I want the data to always go Down instead of it gets under the first copy? What should i change?
2. I have protected everything, but when i run the code it cant copy over because it is protected - what can i do to change that?

Thank you so much, sir! You have helped me enormously.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by down? If you are copying the same data and you simply want to overwrite then  change this  targetSheet.Range("A" & nextRow) to this targetSheet.Range("A1")

Comment: Hello sir, Again - I dont want to overwrite it, but when i let the macro run come up on the top and the older Down just move Down, if it makes sense.

Comment: About the protected sheets, i have this code: Sub Workbook_Open()
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 For Each ws In Sheets

 With ws
 .Unprotect Password:="MKM"
 .Protect Password:="MKM", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
 .EnableOutlining = True
 End With

 Next ws

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 End Sub"

When i use your code with this one, it would not run, because it cant copy to a protected sheets - I want it all to be protected, but how can i also copy to another sheets and still let be protected?

Comment: Thank for you time, sir - I´m really appreciate!
- When i try to run it know, it says the passwords is wrong, even though i try to put it as it is - Can i maybe send you the file on e-mail?

Comment: No it dosent? I dont know why.

Comment: Just tried, and it cant figure it out - Error 1004 comes up - Should i send you the file maybe?

Comment: I have just copied and pasted yours? Isnt it better to send you the file maybe?

Comment: I had thise error before and im actually pretty sure it has something to do with the password - The sheets names are all fine.

Comment: Now try changing the password to something else and run it - i wont, right?

Comment: I once protected with a password and then i changed it and it the error 1004 came always up, then i change the password back Again and was solved - But this time nothing of it Works.

Comment: I know the password - I dont know why it comes up, this times, but it must have something to do with the password i guess.